# How to transform ticks into minute bars in SQL

Tags: sql

I have market data stored in a table in the following format:

```
Timestamp           Price   Quantity    Condition
01/11/2016 09:03:57 14.34   1           S
01/11/2016 09:03:58 14.31   5   
01/11/2016 09:03:59 14.34   1           S
01/11/2016 09:03:59 14.35   2   
etc.
```

I want to group this into bars of one minute length, looking something like this:

```
BarEndTime          Open    High    Low     Close
01/11/2016 09:03    14.15   14.16   14.13   14.15
01/12/2016 09:04    14.17   14.19   14.17   14.18
```

How do I group this data into one minute clusters based on the timestamp of the base data set?  I do this fairly easily in R, but for a number of reasons I'd like to build these in SQL as well.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: "Bars" (buckets) and "clusters" are usually different things in context.  Which do you really mean?  Hint: buckets (fixed) are easy, clusters (variable) are hard...

Answer (score 1):

I have no knowledge of R therefore I can only guess what "buckets" and "cluster" are. But *if, by any chance* you should be interesed in the *opening, minimum, maximum* and *closing* values of `Price`for each minute interval then the following might be helpful:

```
;WITH cte AS (
 SELECT CONVERT(char(16),Timestamp,126) ts, MIN(Price) p0, MAX(Price) p1,
 MIN(Timestamp) t0, MAX(Timestamp) t1
 FROM #tbl GROUP BY CONVERT(char(16),Timestamp,126)
)
SELECT ts,(SELECT min(Price) FROM #tbl WHERE Timestamp=t0) po,
       p0,p1,
       (SELECT max(Price) FROM #tbl WHERE Timestamp=t1) pc
FROM cte
```

See [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/422195/opening-low-hight-and-closing-prices-for-each-minute-interval) for an example.

Input:

```
Timestamp             Price  Qty Cnd
01/11/2016 09:03:57   14.34    1   S
01/11/2016 09:03:58   14.31    5   
01/11/2016 09:03:59   14.34    1   S
01/11/2016 09:03:59   14.35    2   
01/11/2016 09:04:37   11.84    1   S
01/11/2016 09:04:48   12.36    5   
01/11/2016 09:04:49   14.54    1   S
01/11/2016 09:04:59   13.35    2
```

Output:

```
ts               po    p0    p1    pc
2016-01-11T09:03 14.34 14.31 14.35 14.35
2016-01-11T09:04 11.84 11.84 14.54 13.35
```

Since according to the sample data there can be *more than one* `Price` for a particular `Timestamp` given I had to equip the `(SELECT min(Price) FROM #tbl WHERE Timestamp=t0)` subquery for the opening and closing prices with a `min()/max()` aggregate function. Maybe you can find a better solution to limit these subqueries to just a one-value result.

In my solution I used a common table expression (CTE), which is not available in some database systems like MySql. So, in case you are using a RDBS *without* CTE you can easily rewrite the above using a simple subquery since the cte is only referenced once anyway:

```
SELECT ts,(SELECT min(Price) FROM #tbl WHERE Timestamp=t0) po,p0,p1,
       (SELECT max(Price) FROM #tbl WHERE Timestamp=t1) pc
FROM 
(SELECT CONVERT(char(16),Timestamp,126) ts, MIN(Price) p0, MAX(Price) p1,
 MIN(Timestamp) t0, MAX(Timestamp) t1
 FROM #tbl GROUP BY CONVERT(char(16),Timestamp,126)) subq
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Oracle:
   calculating open as the value occurring first in a minute (lowest value if more than one on the first timestamp, and close being the last occurring value ina minute (higher of the values if multiples exist with the same timestamp), analytics become your friend.

```
with dat as(
SELECT to_Date('01/11/2016 09:03:57','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ts, 14.34 val,  1 qty,  'S' cond from dual union all
SELECT to_Date('01/11/2016 09:03:58','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ts, 14.31 val,   5 qty,  null cond from dual union all
SELECT to_Date('01/11/2016 09:03:59','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ts, 14.34 val,   1qty,   'S' cond from dual union all
SELECT to_Date('01/11/2016 09:03:59','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ts,  14.35 val,   2 qty, null cond from dual union all  
SELECT to_Date('01/11/2016 09:03:51','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ts,  14.35 val,   2 qty, null cond from dual union all
SELECT to_Date('01/11/2016 09:04:09','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ts,  14.45 val,   2 qty, null cond from dual union all  
SELECT to_Date('01/11/2016 09:04:19','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ts,  14.15 val,   2 qty, null cond from dual union all  
SELECT to_Date('01/11/2016 09:04:29','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ts,  14.55 val,   2 qty, null cond from dual union all  
SELECT to_Date('01/11/2016 09:04:39','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ts,  14.85 val,   2 qty, null cond from dual union all  
SELECT to_Date('01/11/2016 09:04:49','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ts,  14.45 val,   2 qty, null cond from dual union all  
SELECT to_Date('01/11/2016 09:04:59','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ts,  14.25 val,   2 qty, null cond from dual )
select trunc(ts,'mi') as ts_minute, 
       min (val) keep  (dense_rank first order by ts) as open_val,
       max (val) keep  (dense_rank last order by ts) as close_val,
       min (val) min_val,
       max(val) max_val
from dat
group by trunc(ts,'mi') ;       



 TS_MINUTE,            OPEN_VAL,  CLOSE_VAL,   MIN_VAL,   MAX_VAL
01/11/2016 9:03:00 AM, 14.35,     14.35,       14.31,     14.35
01/11/2016 9:04:00 AM, 14.45,     14.25,       14.15,     14.85
```